# Pandas DataFrame arithmetic

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

Say you have a `DataFrame` with n rows, in this case 3 rows:

```
    High  Low  
0   100  90
1   110  95     
2   105  80
```

I would like to compute the biggest difference between a row, and it's subsequent rows as follows.

So for example, the first computation is the High of the first row, subtracting the low of all rows: 100 - 90, 100 - 95 and 100 - 80. The biggest of those differences is 20. Move to the next row, 110 - 95, 110 - 80. The biggest of those differences is 30. Move on to the final row, 105 - 80 = 25. So the biggest of all the differences is 30, so I want to return the tuple (110, 80), or equivalently, where the `loc` of the `DataFrame` are, (1, 2)

I know I can use two `for loop`. Is there a `pythonic` or `pandas-onic`, I guess `functional` way to do this?

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to `df['High'].argmax(), df['Low'].argmin()` ? That's vectorized and pretty fast.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I though it was obvious, but no. @NickODell these are not equivalent: not all cartesian product items are taken into account, but only union of `product([df.High[i], df.Low[i:])` - e.g. `(110, 90)` pair does not appear. If you swap 1st and 3rd rows in example, `(df.High.argmax(), df.Low.argmin())` will be an incorrect answer, because `Low = 80` precedes `High = 100`.

Answer (score 2):

Not the prettiest solution, but you can leverage the `:=` operator:

```py
_, h, l, idx_high, idx_low = max(
    (
        (
            idxm:=((h:=df.at[i, "High"]) - (d2:=df.loc[i:, "Low"])).idxmax(),
            h,
            d2[idxm],
            i,
            idxm
        )
        for i in df.index
    ),
    key=lambda x: x[1] - x[2],
)
print(h, l, idx_high, idx_low)
```

Prints:

```
110 80 1 2
```

Comment: This works. I havde to give you credit. Boy,  it is a bit messy, but IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easier if you split up the steps of finding the start and end of the range. You can avoid doing a nested loop over the dataframe to compute this by doing the following:

1. For each row, find the smallest value that Low will have for that row or any subsequent row. This is the same as `cummin()`, except that `cummin()` moves forward through the array, and we want it to move backwards. So, reverse the array before and after applying `cummin()`.
2. Next, compare each value of High to the smallest future Low. This will give you the index of the start of your range.
3. Now that you know the start of your range, search for the lowest value which occurs at or after the range. This is equivalent to searching for the value which maximizes the difference between High and Low. (Assuming that High > Low.)

```py
lowest_future_value = df['Low'][::-1].cummin()[::-1]
hi_start = (df['High'] - lowest_future_value).argmax()
lo_end = df['Low'].iloc[hi_start:].argmin() + hi_start
hi_start, lo_end
```

This solution works in O(N) time, whereas a solution using a nested loop takes O(N^2) time.

*Edit*: Here's an alternative implementation of the `df['Low'][::-1].cummin()[::-1]` step, which tracks the index each value came from.

```
def backwards_cummin_with_index(series):
    smallest = None
    smallest_idx = None
    ret = []
    for i, s in reversed(list(series.items())):
        if smallest is None or s < smallest:
            smallest = s
            smallest_idx = i
        ret.append((smallest, smallest_idx))
    return reversed(ret)
```

Comment: Thanks. Thing is, I think this algorithm computes all low mins. I need the biggest spread from a High to a future low, not all lows including those in the past from a given high.

Comment: Your lowest_future_value is not from a row forward, it seems to be from all rows?

Comment: @Ivan Right - that's what the variable `lowest_future_value` is tracking. It's the minimum value of rows with an index equal to or greater than the current row.

Comment: Nick, can you add the indices of where this occurred? It helps debug it? so (high_start, hi_index), (low_end, lo_index) ?

Comment: @Ivan I've added an equivalent implementation of `df['Low'][::-1].cummin()[::-1]`, which you can use to see where it's getting each value from.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting with [`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) to only get the relevant combinations:

```
a = np.triu(df['High'].to_numpy()[:, None]-df['Low'].to_numpy())

idx = np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
# (1, 2)

values = df.loc[df.index[idx[0]], 'High'], df.loc[df.index[idx[1]], 'Low']
# (110, 80)
```

Intermediate `a`, only the upper triangle is relevant:

```
array([[10,  5, 20],
       [ 0, 15, 30],
       [ 0,  0, 25]])
```